# LINQ join on columns AND nullable variable

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to join tables using LINQ by matching columns where a column in the joined table is equal to a variable or the variable is null (at which point the join still needs to happen just not on that field).

My LINQ is something like:

```
var data = (
    from lt in cxt.CmsPageRow
    join page in cxt.CmsPage on new { lt.CmsPageID, cmsSiteID.Value } equals new { page.CmsPageID, page.CmsSiteID }
    ...
```

cmsSiteID is a nullable INT.

I cannot compile my code as it is complaining about "Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'."

On top of that I need to only join on page.CmsSiteID when cmsSiteID is not null. If cmsSiteID is null then the join on lt.CmsPageID still needs to happen.

*** EDIT ***

The question has kind of changed now. I can get it to do what I want by using a WHERE clause on the join in my LINQ.

```
join page in cxt.CmsPage.Where(p=>(cmsSiteID==0||p.CmsSiteID==cmsSiteID)) on lt.CmsPageID equals page.CmsPageID
```

However, this still runs slow. If I change the parameter passed through to a literal it executes instantly.

Slow runner

```
(@p__linq__1 = 0 OR [Extent2].[CmsSiteID] = @p__linq__1)
```

Fast runner

```
(267 = 0 OR [Extent2].[CmsSiteID] = 267)
```

Is there a way to speed this up?

Comment: Where is `cmsSiteID` coming from? Is that a variable declared elsewhere?

Comment: And are you actually selecting something from the `page`, or are you using it purely to know how many items to pull from it? If you are selecting something from it, would you expect those values to be null if `cmsSiteID` is null?

Comment: cmsSiteID is a nullable parameter in the function being called that executes the LINQ. cmsSiteID is not likely to ever be null except I am editing existing code that may have methods elsewhere that do not include the newly added cmsSiteID parameter.

Comment: So if someone provides a CmsSiteId, should it include items that have a null CmsSiteId?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`join` in LINQ assumes an inner join (no nulls). Try pulling the null stuff out into separate `where` clauses. I think something along these lines should work for what you're describing.

```
from lt in cxt.CmsPageRow
join page in cxt.CmsPage on lt.CmsPageID == page.CmsPageID
where cmsSiteID == null || 
      (cmsSiteID != null && (page.CmsSiteID == null || page.CmsSiteId == cmsSiteID.Value))
select ...
```

#### Update

I didn't realize that performance was an issue for you. In that case, I'd suggest creating a different query structure based on values that are known at run-time and don't depend on individual rows:

```
var rows = 
    from lt in cxt.CmsPageRow
    join page in cxt.CmsPage on lt.CmsPageID == page.CmsPageID
    select new {lt, page};
if (cmsSiteID != null)
{
    rows = rows.Where(r => r.page.CmsSiteID == null || 
                           r.page.CmsSiteId == cmsSiteID.Value));
}
var data = rows.Select(...);
```

Also, if your data context is set up right, you should be able to use navigation properties to simplify your code somewhat.

```
var rows = ctx.CmsPageRow;
if (cmsSiteID != null)
{
    rows = rows.Where(r => r.CmsPage.Any(p => p.CmsSiteID == null || 
                               p.CmsSiteId == cmsSiteID.Value));
}
var data = rows.Select(...);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this puts the SQL WHERE clause in the wrong place for me. LINQ is creating SQL that includes an inner select which is where I need the where clause (or directly on the inner join within this inner select). Having it coded like you suggest keeps to the current 6 second execution while putting the cmsSiteID on the inner join makes it work in less than 1/10th of a second. Which is why I want to add this to the LINQ.

Comment: It gets worse now. Setting it as a variable still seems to be crazy slow. Only a literal INT value seems to run fast.

Comment: While this couldn't work for me exactly as prescribed because there were a lot of other joins I never included in my examples it certainly sent me in the right direction. I added a line before my data object of "var pageData = (cmsSiteID == 0) ? cxt.CmsPage : cxt.CmsPage.Where(p => (cmsSiteID != 0 && p.CmsSiteID == cmsSiteID));" and a join of "join page in pageData on lt.CmsPageID equals page.CmsPageID" which worked a treat.

Comment: Point of interest, and pretty much the need for this change, the SQL generated by LINQ was running very slow with the SQL as listed above. By using the "pageData" object it removed the need for the "@p__linq__1 = 0 OR " code. This wasn't enough on it's own but the SQL needed "(@p__linq__1 <> 0) AND " to truly hum.